# How to detect touch position after touchcancel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, swipe

I want to enable both vertical scrolling and horizontal swiping at the same time. I detect the touch position in `touchmove` instead of `touchend`, because I need real-time coordinates. Unfortunatelly, Chrome for Android fires `touchcancel` right after `touchstart`, so no more `touchmove` is fired. This `touchcancel` event can be avoided by calling `event.preventDefault()` from either `touchstart` or `touchmove`. But scrolling becomes disabled this way, so my first approach is to go without `event.preventDefault()`, and use some alternative method instead to detect touch position after `touchcancel`. Is it possible?

Comment: same problem here, did you find an answer? somewhere else?

Comment: You can reimplement scrolling manually.